# Graph Node Spacing And Annotations

Tags: graphics

I am looking to auto gap the nodes in this latex code so they do not overlap. I have a number of graphs to do so ideally don't want to be inserting a tonne of blanks to space them out. Is there a neat way of doing this please? I tired adding `node distance=3cm` and `5cm` in the `[]` but it didn't help.

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}, -]

\node{${aaa}$}
    child { node {${aaa}$} 
        child { node {${aaa}$} 
            child { node{${aaa}$} } 
    child { node{${aaa}$} } }
        child { node {${aaa}$} } }
    child { node {${aaa}$}
            child { node{${aaa}$}
    child { node{${aaa}$} } }
        child { node {${aaa}$} } } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

With package `forest`, which is based on TikZ package, is simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
      draw, semithick,
      shape = circle,
              % style of tree (edges, distances)
       edge = {draw, semithick},
      s sep = 8mm,    % minimum sibling distance between nodes at any tree level
               }
[${aaa}$
    [${aaa}$
        [${aaa}$
            [${aaa}$]
            [${aaa}$]
        ]
        [${aaa}$]
    ]
    [${aaa}$
        [${aaa}$
            [${aaa}$]
        ]
        [${aaa}$]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

With pure TikZ tree you need to determine appropriate sibling distance by hand  (in comparison to forest not as minimal distance between nodes at any level but 
 for each level /where is needed/ separately):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5mm]{standalone}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle},
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=33mm}, % increased
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=22mm}, % decreased,
                        ]
\node{${aaa}$}
    child { node {${aaa}$}
        child { node {${aaa}$}
            child { node{${aaa}$} }
    child { node{${aaa}$} } }
        child { node {${aaa}$} } }
    child { node {${aaa}$}
            child { node{${aaa}$}
    child { node{${aaa}$} } }
        child { node {${aaa}$} } } ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```